# Model state error filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, asp.net-core-mvc

On my DTO objects I have several attributes to check it's validity

And I catch such a body response when validation is failed

```
{
    "TransactionId": [
    "Max length is 20"
    ],
    "AdditionalInfo": [
    "Additional Info has to be no longer than 30 chars"
    ]
}
```

But I need to unify all the errors to be with "Error" key.
Something like that

```
{
    "Error": [
    "Max length is 20",
    "Additional Info has to be no longer than 30 chars"
    ]
}
```

I wrote special filter and registered it in Startup.cs

```
public class ModelStateErrorHandlingFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.ModelState.SetModelValue("Errors", new ValueProviderResult(new StringValues(context.ModelState.ToString())));
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing changes. I also have tried to change the key, but it has privat setter

Comment: You would need to provide you own custom `IActionResult` or build  the desired object model and pass it to an `ObjectResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to provide you own custom `IActionResult` or build  the desired object model and pass it to an appropriate `ObjectResult`.

```
public class ModelStateErrorHandlingFilter : IAsyncActionFilter {
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) {
            var model = new {
                Error = context.ModelState
                    .SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors)
                    .Select(modelError => modelError.ErrorMessage)
                    .ToArray()
            };
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult (model);
        } else {
            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

setting `context.Result` will short-circuit the request and pass it your custom response with desired content.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it could've been done using context.Modelstate

Comment: @rfedytc Had the same requirement for a tag helper and used the same approach of building the error notification message in the view. Glad it helped you. Happy coding.